# Why is the indexing in Laurent series seemingly random?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, laurent-series

Question 3 (Sec. 68) in Complex Variables and Applications 9th ed asks

> Find the Laurent series that represents the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1+z^2)} $ when $1<|z|<\infty$.

---

My result works out as $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{z^{2n+3}}$$

but the book gives solution as $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}}$$
I understand this is just a matter of indexing but is there some sort of pattern or standard choosing of indexing? Some questions' solutions starts infinite sum at $n=0$ while others $n=1$, why is this?

Comment: No, there is no "pattern" or "why."  People choose the notation they choose because they think it is the easiest way to read/write in that notation.

Comment: Your expression makes the degree of the leading term more apparent, and it's generally cleaner to start an alternating sum at $n=0$ than at $n=1$. On the other hand, if you're adding or comparing more than one series, then you may want the expressions for the degree of $z$ to match, and $\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}}$ is more likely to show up than $\frac{1}{z^{2n+3}}$ in the other ones.